# Make JS functions more efficient and dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these 3 functions currently used in a html page:

```
$('#windowPanel1:first-child').children('div:eq(0)').click(function(){
    $('#edit1').val("1");
});
$('#windowPanel1:first-child').children('div:eq(1)').click(function(){
   $('#edit1').val("2");
});
$('#windowPanel1:first-child').children('div:eq(2)').click(function(){
    $('#edit1').val("3");
});
```

I would like to have one function that covers all these functions. What would be the most efficient way? Thanks!

Comment: Although @Tushar answer will do what your after,.  Looking at your code I would say is a perfect candidate for a data attribute.  Especially if it's more than linear sequence like 1,2,3..

Answer (score 6):

Bind the event on all the direct descendant `div` elements of `#windowPanel1:first-child` element. Use [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the index of the clicked element. The `index` returned is zero-based index.

```
$('#windowPanel1:first-child > div').click(function() {
    $('#edit1').val($(this).index() + 1);
});
```

`>` is [direct descendant/child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) which will return same elements as `.children('div')`.